# Can't connect to PostgreSQL with Spring Boot 1.5.x

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I tried to create an empty spring boot 1.5 application with PostgreSQL 9.4 and 9.6 and i got this exception. BUT it works fine when i use Spring Boot 2.0.x ?!

Why is it telling me my password is incorrect ? It works fine when i connect on pgadmin 3 or 4.

**this is the error**

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO8859_1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/GCdb
spring.datasource.username=postgres 
spring.datasource.password=admin   
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

**pom.xml**

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo-3</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo-3</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.14.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: remove the spaces in the end of your username and password

Comment: which spaces ? sorry dont see what you are talking about

Comment: I note that after `postgres` you have a space **"postgres "** and same after `admin` **"admin  "**

Comment: Im not using spaces, as you can see in my application properties.

Comment: There is a space after postgres and 3 spaces after admin. In your post, try highlighting the all the properties and you will see spaces at the end. just checked, trailing spaces are not trimmed by property loader.

Comment: there are spaces in your "postgress" and "admin"..if you want to check then go to edit section of this question and click in the text area after "postgress" and "admin".

Comment: Thanks guys ! it works fine ! Really weird problem, but why it works fine with Spring Boot 2 ?